# duda sobre desreferencia de iteradores, c++

Tags: c++, qt

en mi programa tengo creada una lista enlazada y quiero recorrerla con un iterador y en una posicion x modificar un valor de la lista.
he buscando en internet y he visto varios ejemplos pero no me funciona ninguno, creo que hay algo basico que estoy haciendo mal, el codigo:

```
...
list<Avion>::iterator it;   //creando iterador

it =  flotaAviones.begin(); //igualando iterador a principio de lista

while (*it == false)
{
```

en esta linea, despues del punto segun los ejemplos que he visto en internet deberian salir todos los metodos y atributos de la clase avion, pues con el iterador estoy apuntando al lugar de la lista donde se guarda un objeto tipo avion. Pues esto no sucede)

Answer (score 3):

Ese código tiene un problema importante:

```
while (*it == false)
```

`*it` desreferencia el iterador... lo que hace esa línea es comparar un objeto de tipo `Avion` con `false`. Saca tus propias conclusiones...

Adicionalmente, no veo ni dónde ni cómo estás desplazándote por la lista... aunque asumo que eso lo haces en algún sitio y que esa parte funciona.

`std::list` proporciona dos iteradores: `begin` y `end`. Mientras que el primero te devuelve un iterador al inicio de la lista, el segundo te devuelve un iterador que indica que has llegado al final de la lista.

Con todo esto, para iterar por toda la colección podrías hacer esto:

```
for( it = flotaAviones.begin(); it != flotaAviones.end(); ++it )
```

O, si no quieres pedir el `end` en cada iteración porque te parece *poco eficiente*:

```
for( list<Avion>::iterator it = flotaAviones.begin(), itEnd = flotaAviones.end(); it != itEnd; ++it )
```

O, si además puedes permitirte el *lujo* de usar el estándar C++11 (Data de 2011... toda una novedad!!!), podrías usar una de estas dos versiones:

```
for( auto it = flotaAviones.begin(), itEnd = flotaAviones.end(); it != itEnd; ++it )

for( Avion& avion : flotaAviones )
```

Nota que en este último caso no tienes iteradores, este `for` usa los iteradores internamente y te da acceso a los elementos de la lista directamente

Comment: La pregunta original no era asi, fue editada, por eso no se entiende , quedaria :::   while ((*it)./*metodo*/ == false), y lo que preguntaba era pq no autocompletaba el IDE con los atributos y funciones del tipo de dato de la lista a la que hace referencia el iterador it.

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR edita entonces la pregunta,  por favor. Yo edité la pregunta porque estaba mal formateada, el código que comentas ya no existía... o yo no lo vi.

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR también sería conveniente que incluyeses la interfaz de `Avion`